# Core Data: NSFetchedResultsController error: Attempt to create Two Animations

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Has anyone been able to solve what causes this error to occur,

"CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Attempt to create two animations for cell with userInfo (null)"

Seems like its more of a tableview issue then core data

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time since I worked with core data and the table view updates, but I'd suggest to look for multiple cell updates ending up at one cell.

For instance if two records have been deleted, the change should propagate to the table view. If these two deletions are propagated as "remove cell 7" (two times) while it should be cell 7 and 8, it might explain the error. Maybe an index value is calculated and after the first deletion that index needs to be adjusted or recalculated, but it is not and thus points to the wrong cell for the next deletion.